# Calculating large number of generalized eigenvalues with Matlab on GPU

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, gpgpu

I have a lot of small matrices already stored on GPU card and now I want to calculate their generalized eigenvalues with another matrix.

Current code:

```
cov=gpuArray(cov) %7x7 matrix;
p=1:numel(ix1); %numel(ix1)... number of stored matrices
p=gpuArray(p);
%covs... 7x7xn matrix already on GPU, n is large (>100000)
g = arrayfun(@(x) eig(covs(:,:,x)/cov), p);
```

If I tried to run code I get error that function eig is unsupported, but I read that eig is supported on GPU.

So my question is what I did wrong (my first attempt with arrayfun) and if there is better way to calculate generalized eigenvalues.

Comment: From the documentation on [`arrayfun`](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/arrayfun.html) for the GPU, click through to [this page](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/run-element-wise-matlab-code-on-a-gpu.html#bsnx7h8-1), which shows you `eig` is in fact not included in the list of functions that support GPU computing.

Comment: Try a for loop instead, and compare the performance GPU / CPU if the speed is not satisfying. I am not sure if a GPU is really faster for such small matrices.

Comment: @Adriaan thanks for link I saw that eig was included in list to able to run on GPU, but didnt know that arrayfun has even more limitations.